# Equality of iterates produced by Minres and GMres for practically symmetric matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

My system is from time-integration of the semi-discretized Stokes equation. The time update of the variables $(v,p)$ is defined via the solution of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 A & -\tau B^T \\ B & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 v \\p
\end{bmatrix} = f \quad\quad (*)
$$
or, equivalently, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B^T \\ B & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 v \\ \tilde p
\end{bmatrix} = f, \quad\quad (**)
$$
where $\tilde p := -\tau p$.

Note that, since $A$ is assumed symmetric, the coefficient matrix in $(**)$ is symmetric.

Say, I start with a zero initial value and I use *GMRes* to solve $(*)$ and *MinRes* to solve $(**)$ iteratively.

**Question**: Do the iterates -- after rescaling $p:=-\frac{1}{\tau}\tilde p$ -- of both iteration schemes coincide?

If not, can I say something about the approximation quality of $p$ in the *MinRes* iteration for $(**)$ taking into account that $\tau \ll 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, the iterates do not coincide, see the [numerical experiment](https://gist.github.com/andrenarchy/9783314) with [KryPy](https://github.com/andrenarchy/krypy). Note that GMRES can be used in both cases since MINRES is (mathematically) equivalent to GMRES.

**Long answer:** applying GMRES to $(**)$ and correcting afterwards is equivalent to applying GMRES to $(*)$ with the *right* preconditioner
$$
M_r=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\ 0& -\tau I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In general, the Krylov subspace $K_n(C,f)$ for $(*)$ does not equal $K_n(CM_r,f)$ for $(**)$ (where $C$ is the block matrix in $(*)$). Thus, the iterates will not coincide in general. Furthermore, I am not aware of any possibility to relate the iterates in a meaningful way.